# I have psd file and i want to convert to bootstrap 3 if its possible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, psd

PsD file.
Can you provide little solution for beginning my project.Thanks a lot.
I have tried some examples but i cant do nothing.

Comment: http://psdtobootstrap.com/

Comment: Expect you to try yourself first. Google wisely, you will get lot of suggestion. If you are stuck then we are here to guide and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download bootstrap basic files that includes .js, css, fonts- from here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Download the first option (Named Bootstrap) [Link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.7/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist.zip)

2. Create an HTML page with your software (eg: Adobe Dreamweaver, Sublime etc)

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. Include the downloaded css & js files.
4. Now you can start the writing codes, there is lot of css styles in bootstrap.min.css stylesheet. Additional styles that you need to create an extra css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.
Bootstrap is a framework to help you with the creation of web pages.
PSD can be exported as images. Maybe with some basic HTML tags, but it won't be exported has a responsive website with CSS or bootstrap elements.

Comment: I want make it with bootstrap to do it responsive.Is it possible to make it only with bootstrap?.Can i use class .container couple of times?.